# How can I show a pop-up only once within a 6 month period, after 3 pagevisits, and to only 20% of all visitors?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm not very good at JavaScript, but I tried.  In the following code, I do have the pop-up showing only after 3 pageviews, and at a 20% sampling rate, and I have a cookie expiring in 6 months, but can not figure out how to add (I guess via 'if' statement) to show the pop-up only once during the 6 month time period.  Any help would be so very appreciated.

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {

    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString() : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name) {

    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin === -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin !== 0) return null;
    } else {
        begin += 2;
    }
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    if (end === -1) {
        end = dc.length;
    }
    return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}


visits = getCookie('nVisits');
if (!visits) {
    visits = 1
}
if (visits == 3)
    if ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) < 20) {
        window.open("https://www.mypopup.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    }
if (visits < 3) {
    ++visits;
    cookieData = visits;
    setCookie('nVisits', cookieData, expDate)
}


expDate = new Date;
// in the following line, 180 means 180 days. 
expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
expDate.toUTCString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in condition:

```
if (visits == 3)
    if ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) < 20) {
    window.open("https://www.mypopup.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
}    
if (visits < 3) {
    ++visits;
    cookieData = visits;
    setCookie('nVisits', cookieData, expDate)
}
```

You increment the visits only up to three. But when it is three, it remains three forever.

=> always increase the cookie (-> remove the if (visits < 3)) or in if(visits === 3) change the counter to 4. Or add flag Showned. Or something similar.

---

And one general thought: The code doesn't explain the purpose but bare in mind, that one user can use more devices/browsers, clean cookies, use cookie blocker and similar.

Comment: sorry I'm confused (totally normal for me).  Change the visits from < 3; to < 4?

Comment: Well, you increment visits up to 3. And then it never change. -> the condition `visits === 3` will match everytime. -> you have to make `visits` unmatch the condition somehow. Either increment it or whatever.